# C++ can't get number of lines txt file

Tags: c++, line, eof, txt

I'm trying to get the number of lines in a txt file. This is the method I've been trying to implement, but it prints n=1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n=0;
    string line;

    ifstream fdatos;
    fdatos.open("temp_toma5.txt");
    
    while (!fdatos.eof()){
        getline(fdatos, line);
        n++;
    }

    cout<<"n = "<<n<<endl<<endl;
    fdatos.close();
return 0;
}
```

This is the structure of the file

```
0   0.03    0
5   0.03    0.01
10  0.02    0
15  0.02    0
20  0.02    0
25  0.03    0
30  0.03    0
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Worthwhile reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Please take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it. Like telling us what happens, and what should happen.

Comment: _"it's not working and I don't know why"_ does not describe a specific behavior or ask a question.  At best, it is a complaint.  This could mean almost anything.  Does your code even compile?  Does it successfully open the file?  Does it output a value different from what you expect?  Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this

```
while (getline(fdatos, line))
    ++n;
```

`getline` returns false at the end of file because it picks up an "empty line".

Full working snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    int n = 0;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream fdatos("temp_toma5.txt");

    while (std::getline(fdatos, line))
        ++n;

    std::cout << "n = " << n << "\n\n";

    fdatos.close();
    return 0;
}
```

gives the right answer `n = 7`.

The comment of user4581301 points to the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: I need to split some hairs here...  `getline` does not _"return false at the end of the file"_.  It returns a stream reference, always.  When you use the return value this way, the stream is implicitly cast to bool, invoking the bool operator overload for streams which tests if the `fail` bit is set.  That indicates that a read failed which may be the result of end-of-file _and_ no characters read, or the stream being closed, or some other I/O error.  In this case, the operator returns false.  If no failure occurred, it returns true.

Comment: That's right, it returns a reference to the input stream, for which the standard has a clear definition for bool casting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool
Apologies for my sloppiness.

Comment: I did not hammer the question shut as a duplicate because we don't know for certain that this is the bug the asker is hunting. It's definitely a bug, but for all we know they aren't successfully opening the file because temp_toma5.txt" isn't in the working directory